# Server to Server OAuth with Netlify API using "Authorization Code Grant"

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, netlify

I'm trying to do Server to Server auth with netlify.com

I can find examples for authentication on behalf of users, but the type of authentication that I want to do - "Authorization Code Grant" has no examples.

I've been looking at this link for answers.

[Netlify OAuth2](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/10/10/integrating-with-netlify-oauth2/)

I'm also unsure whether I should be setting up an OAuth App on Netlify or a Personal Access Token.

My current code (RUBY) is returning a status 200 + HTML page.

Code that I am currently attempting to Auth with

```
def auth_get(client_id)
  # /authorize
  uri = URI('https://app.netlify.com')

  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/api/v1/authorize?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=#{client_id}")
  response = http.request(request)
end
```

When I run the HTML page, I get an error.

> Page not found
>
> You might not have permissions to see this page.

Comment: I've got the same issue, did you resolve this?

Comment: No I didn't, can't remember what I did here

Comment: I contacted their support. I don't think that they've implemented `code` grant type, without providing a way to handle it. It's simply not documented at the moment; I did find another way to authenticate with tickets, but that's not standard OAuth2 flow.

Comment: Same issue even on 2022/05 :(